# pandas plot with different variable for subplots and colour?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Currently this code:

```
count_df = (df[['rank', 'name', 'variable', 'value']]
    .groupby(['rank', 'variable', 'name'])
    .agg('count')
    .unstack())
count_df .head()
#               value                          
# name           1lin STH_km27_lin ST_lin S_lin
# rank variable                                
# 1.0  NEE         24          115     33    28
#      Qg          23           54     14     9
#      Qh          37          124     11    28
# ...
count_df.plot(kind='bar')
```

gets me this plot:

[image: bar plot with too much shit on it]

using `subplots=True` in the `.plot()` call gets me this:

[image: useless subplots]

which is pretty useless, because the colours are mapped to the same variable as the subplot facetting. Is there a way to choose which column/index is used for the sub-plotting, so that I can still have colours per `name` (`count_df` column header), but sub-plots per `variable`, so that each subplot has a bar per `name/rank`, grouped by `rank`, and coloured by `name`?

Answer (score 2):

Hrm. I suspect this isn't doable in pandas by itself, but I found a way to do it in Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

cdf = (df[['rank', 'name', 'variable', 'value']]
           .groupby(['rank', 'variable', 'name'])
           .agg('count'))
sns.factorplot(x="rank", y="value", row="variable", hue="name",
               data=cdf.reset_index(), kind='bar')
```

which results in:

[image: barplot by rank, variable, and name]

which is close enough for my purposes